# SQL Query with results from 2 Tables, 1 table multiple times

Tags: sql-server

I have the following data in SQL tables.

Table 1

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Smith |
| 3 | Jenny |
| 4 | Bill |

Table 2

| _id | value | value_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | New York | 1 |
| 2 | London | 1 |
| 3 | Chicago | 1 |
| 1 | Vegas | 2 |
| 3 | Atlanta | 2 |
| 4 | Tampa Bay | 2 |
| 4 | Paris | 1 |

The result that I'm trying to show is this.

| id | name | city_1 | city_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | New York | Vegas |
| 2 | Smith | London | NULL |
| 3 | Jenny | Chicago | Atlanta |
| 4 | Bill | Tampa Bay | Paris |

But the result I'm getting is this, Row 2 Missing.

| id | name | city_1 | city_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | New York | Vegas |
| 3 | Jenny | Chicago | Atlanta |
| 4 | Bill | Tampa Bay | Paris |

The code I'm using is this.

```sql
SELECT 
     a.id,
     a.name,
     b.value AS city_1, 
     c.value AS city_2 
FROM table1 AS a
JOIN table2 AS b ON a.id=b._id
JOIN table2 AS c ON a.id=c._id
WHERE b.value_id=1 and c.value_id=2
```

Can someone let me know where I'm making a mistake?

Answer (score 3):

Almost there, but you need a couple of changes:

```
    select a.id,a.name, b.value as city_1, c.value as city_2 
    from table1 as a
    left join table2 as b on a.id=b._id and b.value_id=1
    left join table2 as c on a.id=c._id and c.value_id=2
```

Basically, use left joins because you don't always have matching records in the other table, but you'd like to show all the rows in your first table.

Moving the conditions from the where clause to the on clauses in the joins ensures that the conditions are applied during the joins, instead of filtering the results of the joins. If we were to use  the where clause together with left join, you would still see the same result that you do now, because the where would be evaluated after the join.

Comment: Make sure to tick that the answer is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the other answer is multiple joins to the same table. You can do this with a single join, and conditional aggregation (a.k.a `PIVOT`)

```sql
select
    a.id,
    a.name,
    max(case when b.value_id = 1 then b.value end) as city_1,
    max(case when b.value_id = 2 then b.value end) as city_2 
from table1 as a
left join table2 as b on a.id = b._id
group by
    a.id,
    a.name;
```